# eclipse non-extension file syntax highlight

Tags: eclipse, syntax

Computer software question: I have bash files that have no extension. How can I have its syntax highlighted in 
Eclipse. I already have ShellEd installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the file and select `Open with > Shell Script Editor`

I don't think it's possible to open files without extension in a custom editor by default.

Answer (score 2):

from  *Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations*,  add a 'file type' with the name of your file and choose the editor (ShellEd in this case) to associate. You should **restart Eclipse** after this change. This works for me on Eclipse version 4.3 (Kepler).